# Selenium + gradle + testng, UnsatisfiedLinkError on driver.quit()

Tags: java, selenium, gradle, testng

In eclipse, the tests works perfect. I'm running my Selenium tests in gradle and getting error on `@AfterSuite` method in the line

```
driver.quit();
```

build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
version = '1.1'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()  
    maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/libs-release" }
}

dependencies {
compile "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:2.+"
compile "org.testng:testng:6.+"
compile "org.mongodb:mongo-java-driver:3.1.0"
compile "javax.mail:mail:1.4.+"
compile "org.mindrot:jbcrypt:0.3m"

}

tasks.withType(Test) {
    useTestNG()
    systemProperties = System.getProperties()
    ignoreFailures = true            
}
```

Error text:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't obtain updateLastError method for class com.sun.jna.Native
at com.sun.jna.Native.initIDs(Native Method)
at com.sun.jna.Native.<clinit>(Native.java:139)
at org.openqa.selenium.os.Kernel32.<clinit>(Kernel32.java:34)
at org.openqa.selenium.os.ProcessUtils.killWinProcess(ProcessUtils.java:133)
at org.openqa.selenium.os.ProcessUtils.killProcess(ProcessUtils.java:81)
at org.openqa.selenium.os.UnixProcess$SeleniumWatchDog.destroyHarder(UnixProcess.java:247)
at org.openqa.selenium.os.UnixProcess$SeleniumWatchDog.access$200(UnixProcess.java:201)
at org.openqa.selenium.os.UnixProcess.destroy(UnixProcess.java:125)
at org.openqa.selenium.os.CommandLine.destroy(CommandLine.java:155)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxBinary.quit(FirefoxBinary.java:259)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.quit(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:204)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver$LazyCommandExecutor.quit(FirefoxDriver.java:364)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.stopClient(FirefoxDriver.java:310)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.quit(RemoteWebDriver.java:519)
at Main.DriverFactory.afterTest(DriverFactory.java:130)
```

Answer (score 0):

Error was in the line

```
systemProperties = System.getProperties()
```

Probably gradle took additional Properties from command line. I changed it to

```
systemProperties = [
        BROWSER: System.getProperty('BROWSER', 'firefox')
]
```

Now it's working without error.

Comment: This solution doesn't work for me. I have similar problem with chrome driver. How do you use this BROWSER variable in code?

Comment: I'm using it to set up browser and create profile, somethoing like `if (BROWSER.equals("firefox"))`

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. The issue is gone after updating gradle up to 3.1 version.